# I am able to display only first word of fullname i want to display full string

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

    include "dbconfig.php";
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION["session_admin"])=="" || $_SESSION["session_admin"]=="") {

        header("location:index.php");
    }

?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Edit</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
            <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <style type="text/css">
                .form-control
                {
                    width: 300px;
                    /*text-transform: uppercase;*/
                }
                .email
                {
                    /*ext-transform: lowercase;*/
                }
                .btn
                {
                    color: white;
                }

                .error{
                    color: red;
                }

                .right-addon input { padding-right: 0px; }
                .right-addon .glyphicon { right: 0px;} 
            </style>    
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <center><strong><h2>Edit</h2></strong></center>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <?php
                        $get_id=$_GET["id"];
                        $result=mysqli_query($db,"select * from signup where sid=$get_id");
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                        <form method="post" id="signup" role="form">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
                                    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Fullname" value=<?php echo  $row["sfullname"]; ?>>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                                    </div>              
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
                                    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
                                    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">               
                                    <select class="form-control" name="state" style="width: 100px;" >
                                        <option value="">State</option>
                                        <option>Gujrat</option>
                                        <option>Maharashtra</option>
                                        <option>Goa</option>
                                        <option>Rajasthan</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="createpass" placeholder="Create password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">           
                                    <select class="form-control" name="city" style="width: 100px;" >
                                        <option value="">City</option>
                                        <option>Ahmedabad</option>
                                        <option>Mumbai</option>
                                        <option>Kolkata</option>
                                        <option>Delhi</option>
                                        <option>Banglore</option>
                                        <option>Chennai </option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpass" placeholder="Confirm password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                                    <strong>Gender</strong>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group ">           
                                <center>
                                    <!-- <input type="submit" name="sbt" value="Register" class="form-control btn-success"> -->
                                    <button type="submit" name="sbt" class="btn"><span style="color: white;">Update</span></button>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    <?php   }?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Jquery Plugin CDN -->
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <!-- Jquery Validation Plugin CDn -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
            <!-- Linking Page to index.js for form validation -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to display wholw string from my database into textbox but I am only able to display first word of that string. How can I display the whole string?

I have attached 2 images for reference, please look at them. In my database there is `"abc xyz"` in `sfullname` column and when I am selecting it only `"abc"` is displaying in the textbox...please refer images Please look this Database table

[image: Please see this my php page and first textbox]

I want to display wholw string from my database into textbox but I am only able to display first word of that string. How can I display the whole string?

I have attached 2 images for reference, please look at them. In my database there is `"abc xyz"` in `sfullname` column and when I am selecting it only `"abc"` is displaying in the textbox...please refer images Please look this Database table

[image: Please see this my php page and first textbox]

Comment: What happened to good coding practices? How are we supposed to read this?

Comment: You should reduce your code to the minimal relevant part, almost sure nobody will read all this, and it's not really well formatted. Also, using a snippet for PHP code is useless, the PHP won't run here.

Comment: In `value=<?php echo  $row["sfullname"]; ?>` are missing double quotes `value="<?php echo  $row["sfullname"]; ?">`

Comment: If you had inspected the HTML that was  generated, then you should have been able to spot the error. However, the precision with which you typed your question, suggests that you don't have an eye for the level of detain needed for software development.

Answer (score 2):

In your first input look here:

```
value=<?php echo $row["sfullname"]; ?>
```

Your value attribute is unquoted.  Any spaces will result in the output you describe. Besides, it should be html-escaped as well, as a stray quote in the data will result in the same behavior.

Fix by quoting correctly:

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["sfullname"], ENT_QUOTES); ?>"
```

---

While I am here. `empty()` fits better for your `if` statement, so you probably want something more like:

```
if (empty($_SESSION["session_admin"])) {
    header("location:index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Don't forget to exit after a header redirection, else the rest of your code is executed.

Plus mandatory nag about using prepared queries - else you are open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing double quotes in the value attributes, your code looks like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Fullname" value=<?php echo  $row["sfullname"]; ?>>
```

Plese try below one instead of your code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Fullname" value="<?php echo  $row["sfullname"]; ?>">
```